# Why does XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange return status but XMLHttpRequest.onload does not?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am learning to use `XMLHttpRequest` object.
With help from the web, I have written a simple html file to retrieve data and display in the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>XMLHttpRequest</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.onload = function(){
        if(this.status !== 200){
          console.log("Error: " + this.status);
        }
        else{
          document.getElementById("stat").innerHTML = this.status;
          document.getElementById("size").innerHTML = this.response.length;
          document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = JSON.parse(this.response);
        }
      }
      request.open('GET','https://hplussport.com/api/products');
      request.send();
    </script>
    <div>
      Response Data<br/>
      Status: <span id="stat">Loading...</span><br/>
      Size  : <span id="size">Loading...</span> bytes<br/>
      Data  : <span id="data">Loading...</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The request works fine if the URL is correct but if there are any errors in the URL, nothing happens. I understand that if there is no response, then `this.response` will be empty but I thought that `this.status` would still have a value and, therefore, the console would report `"Error" + this.status` however, it doesn't. It does trigger the error report in the console if I change `request.onload` to `request.onreadystatechange` but I get the error reported twice.

So my question is, why does `request.onload` not work and `request.onreadystatechange` does work (twice) and which one should I use? I feel like I *should* use `request.onload`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onload` is triggerd once when the request completes and is a 2xx status. for error codes you would have to add the `onerror = callback`

`onreadystatechange` will be called 4 times no mather what status code you get

1. when it opens a request,
2. when the full request header + body have been sent
3. when the response headers returns (then you know the response status and the response headers)
4. and finally when the hole response body is downloaded

XMLHttpRequest is quite old and have its bugs/quirks that have been fixed in modern browser but there is a newer api called [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) it is a bit more superior cuz you can also stream large data with ReadableStreams + it works well in web workers, Deno and NodeJS too (unlike XMLHttpRequest)
I recommend to learn/use fetch instead

then your code would looks something like this:

```js
var res = await fetch('https://hplussport.com/api/products')
if (response.ok) {
  // status was 2xx
  const json = await res.text()
  document.getElementById("stat").innerHTML = res.status;
  document.getElementById("size").innerHTML = new Blob([text]).size;
  document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = json;
} else {
  // status was not 2xx
  console.log("Error: " + res.status);
}
```

Comment: Thank you - that's a really helpful answer. I will research fetch. Does fetch use 'promises'? I've heard of that.

Comment: Yes, fetch uses promises... Basically everything after `await something` is a promise